# How to compile c++ code with python2.7 i386 when I have 64 bit system with amd64 python installed

Tags: python, c++, linux, ubuntu, virtualenv

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 64 bits. I have instaled python2.7 amd64, and I use the flags 'python-config --cflags' and 'python-config --ldflags' in the makefile.
They show, respectively:

- -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7
  -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
- -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -lpython2.7 -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions

My objective is to develop a 32-bit version with -m32, but I encounter the following error:

```
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:7:49: fatal error: i386-linux-gnu/python2.7/pyconfig.h: File or directory not found.
#  include <i386-linux-gnu/python2.7/pyconfig.h>
                                             ^
compilation terminated.
```

I've researched a lot trying to resolve this problem. I've tried installing python2.7:i386 alongside with python2.7:amd64 but some packages get removed and I had no avail. The only way I've suceeded was setting up a chroot environment on which I installed a pseudo-system for ubuntu trusty 32 bit. Altough I want to know if it's possible to do this with python virtualenv, and if so, could you offer some examples? I could not find nor understand how it can be used to link with my code.

This is the first time I ask a question on this site, I apologize in advance if I did it incorrectly! And thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you installed [multi-arch `gcc`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453681/gcc-wont-link-with-m32)?

Comment: Hello Elliott, I have tried with dpkg --add-architecture i386, but for what I understand the problem is not the compiler, but missing libraries once the flag -m32 makes it look for /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/python2.7, but i386-linux-gnu/python2.7 is inexistent because I can't have installed python2.7 for both architectures. I want to know if there's a way to work with different architectures of python2.7 without using chroot.